# xhtml inside Titanium WebView doesn't fire App level event (Ti.App.fireEvent)

Tags: events, webview, xhtml, titanium, appcelerator

I am developing iOS ePub reader App using Titanium.

I am using a WebView to open a .xhtml file, which is unzipped from a ePub. It differ from .html by having the html tag as

```
<html xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
  xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events">
```

In this xhtml, I fire an event upon user selection, like this:

```
$(function(){    
    /** detect touchend **/
    $(document).bind('touchend', function(e){
        var sel = '';
        if(window.getSelection){
            sel = window.getSelection().toString();

            if( sel.length>0 ){
                $('#debug').html( sel );
                Ti.App.fireEvent('EPubReader:selectText', {text:sel} );
            }
        }
    }); 
});
```

But the event didn't fire even though other script like **$('#debug').html( sel );** can be executed.
However, when I change the file from **.xhtml** to **.html** and replace the html tag with simple  tag. it can fire the event.

Why is it so?

Although it work after modification, I don't prefer modifying every .xhtml file unpacked from an ePub. How can I make it work without changing it from .xhtml to .html ??

Comment: Need more context. Is this script located inside the .xhtml file? If so, take note that XHTML parses inline scripts differently than HTML, and it may help to put the script in a `<![CDATA[` .. `]]>` block. Also, you're not using forbidden things like `document.write`, are you?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

The script is located inside <head> and no, I am not using document.write. Just curious, other than document.write, what else is forbidden?

I will try putting them in CDATA block you mentioned.

Comment: You can't have HTML comments for instance. Here is a nice page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Writing_JavaScript_for_XHTML

Comment: So sad that putting those script in CDATA not working.

And I has try putting those script in external file too, still can't access the Ti API ...